# Problems with default values for updated_at and created_at with SQL migrations in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, default

I'm writing migrations in Rails 3.2 using SQL (i.e. `execute`) to enforce application logic (foreign keys, defaults, checks, triggers) at the database level. The reason is that I want consistent database interactions in case I need to use the same database from different applications (i.e. not Rails) or mass import data directly. Everything seems to work splendidly except for default values **for one model** (see below) .

For example `created_at` would include `NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp`. This is all nice if I create a record in the database, but for some reason schema.rb doesn't detect the default values, but correctly identifies the `NOT NULL` constraint. The consequence is that I can't save an instance in the database using Model.create or Model.new (e.g. `BibliographicItem.create(title: "Foo")`), because `created_at` and `updated_at` end up being `nil` which violates the `null: false` constraint in schema.rb.

The offending table in schema.rb:

```
create_table "bibliographic_items", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "uuid",             :limit => nil, :null => false
  t.string   "title",            :limit => nil, :null => false
  t.integer  "publication_year"
  t.string   "type",             :limit => nil, :null => false
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",                      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      :null => false
end
```

Its model:

```
class BibliographicItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Extensions::UUID
  attr_accessible :title, :publication_year, :description

  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships, order: "role DESC, author_order DESC NULLS LAST"

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }

  validates :publication_year, numericality: { only_integer: true,
                               less_than_or_equal_to: Date.today.year() }
end
```

The table creation in the `execute` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE bibliographic_items (
uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar NOT NULL,
publication_year int CHECK (publication_year <= left(now()::text, 4)::int),
type varchar NOT NULL REFERENCES bibliographic_item_types ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
description text,
created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
CHECK (updated_at >= created_at)
);
```

Why do `.create` and `.new` not assign values for `created_at` and `updated_at`? For all my other models, with similar (but simpler definitions) there is no issue.

Comment: I changed the question, because I didn't understand the scope of the issue initially...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problems, which as it happens, has **nothing** to do with SQL migrations, created_at or schema.rb, but is caused by failing the validation `validates publication_year, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: Date.today.year() }` when publication_year is `nil`.

*Bangs head against wall.*